# How much should I pay if I run aws s3 sync commands in the same bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, price

How much should I pay if I run aws s3 sync commands in the same bucket?
The directory's size is 9.3T with 820156 objects.
I can't figure out through aws document.

Comment: Same as doing it bucket to bucket. and you’re doubling your storage cost

Comment: Yes, it will double my storage cost.

Comment: Yea. You don’t get any savings for doing it within bucket. S3 servers don’t execute s3 commands. The data needs to leave and go back in. So you pay all of the out cost and all of the in cost.

Comment: Is there any documents about this kind of cost? https://amazonaws-china.com/s3/pricing/  Don't know which one is right...

Answer (score 5):

Amazon S3 costs incurred:

- **Storage:** Double (since the data is stored twice)
- **Requests:** PUT, COPY, POST, LIST requests = $0.005 per 1,000 requests (assuming Standard storage). With 820k files, this would cost (at minimum) **around $4.10**.
- **Data Transfer:** None. Same bucket, same region.
- **Management and Replication:** None. Not using these features.

Based on: [Amazon S3 Simple Storage Service pricing - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Please note that the AWS CLI `sync` command would also make additional API calls, such as listing the source and destination to determine which files to copy. Listing a bucket returns only 1000 objects at a time, so listing 820k objects would require 820 API calls. That's only another half a cent.

Comment: Upvoted because this answer gives a good reminds on the cost of requests, many others, include me, focus on using sync to reduce storage size but didn't think about the requests cost, which can be more expensive than the storage, if you use sync for something like daily backup.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the same region you won't be charged a data transfer cost, but if you are to sync between two buckets in different regions (which seems you aren't), then you will have to pay a data transfer cost.

As for the storage costs, if it's the same region- it would just be 2x. If it's in a different region, then the cost per GB will change + the data transfer cost.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ (tab: "Data transfer")

Keep in mind the magnitude of your data by TB will also modify your GB unit cost. The more TB's you have the less cost per GB there will be. Check out the link provided and also use the [AWS Cost Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) provided by AWS